# Oracle to retrieve data

Tags: oracle

I have table with `id, name, update_date` etc. columns.

```
Select distinct id from table1 order by update_date desc;
```

In above query am getting duplicate values as well. I need to retrieve distinct id with having latest updated date.

Comment: Please post your sample data and the output you expect, along with the output you are receiving. This will help people point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this might do the job:

```
select id, 
       max(update_date) max_update_date
from table1
group by id;
```

as

- `MAX` will return the latest UPDATE_DATE
- `GROUP BY` will return `DISTINCT` ID's anyway (so you don't have to specify it)

If it does not, provide test case and explain what output you'd want to get; someone will assist.